# How do you change the express static directories?

Tags: node.js, express, connect

I am working on a development platform, I have code similar to the following:

```
app.use('/public', express.static( config.directory.public ));
```

The issue is that there are many (100s) of projects each with its own directory structure. The project will be selected via the URL:

```
http://localhost/dev/accounts
```

Where accounts is a project with its own directory tree and static public directory.
I do not want to run a separate copy of node for each project. Once a project has been selected via the URL then express needs to be reconfigured to serve files for that request.

However, that approach is probably not feasible because we may be working on many projects at the same time. So every request for static files would have to be processed according to the project URL. It seems to negate the benefit of static directories.

I think what I am after is a way to put variables into the directory path

```
http://localhost/dev/accounts
```

Would set a variable called prj = "accounts" and then somehow set express so that the root directory is "c:\projects\" + prj + "\public". 
If I simply issue a new app.use(..) statement for every request I imagine bad things will happen.

Maybe I am better off just manually reading the file contents for each static request and sending the contents back. 
Is there another way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but express serves static files in file directories automatically for you. If you have a bunch of projects in some 'path/to/public' folder, you just need to do something like

```
app.use('/', express.static( __dirname + '/public' ));
```

That way, you just need to type some url like

```
http://localhost/project1
```

or

```
http://localhost/project2
```